# Why is PF not working on M1?

Tags: apple-silicon, firewall, pfctl

I don't understand why PF does not work on M1. This problem is only on M1.
I tried turning firewall on/off.
PF successfully enabled without my code

/etc/pf.conf

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"

block drop all
pass on lo0
pass on utun0
pass out proto udp from any to 169.38.69.24 port 1194
```

Terminal output:

```
sudo pfctl -e -f /etc/pf.conf    
             
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
/etc/pf.conf:11: syntax error
pfctl: Syntax error in config file: pf rules not loaded
```

And i tried with pf.anchors:
/etc/pf.conf

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"

anchor "org.vpnonly.pf"
load anchor "org.vpnonly.pf" from "/etc/pf.anchors/org.vpnonly.pf.rules"
```

Terminal output:

```
sudo pfctl -e -f /etc/pf.conf    
             
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
/etc/pf.conf:9: syntax error
pfctl: Syntax error in config file: pf rules not loaded
```

/etc/pf.anchors/org.vpnonly.pf.rules

```
# Options
#set block-policy drop
set block-policy return
set fingerprints "/etc/pf.os"
set ruleset-optimization basic
set skip on lo0

wifi=en0
ether=en1

# Interfaces
vpn_intf = "{utun0 utun1 utun2 utun3}"

# Ports
allowed_vpn_ports = "{1194 1195 54563 50000}"

# Table with allowed IPs
table <allowed_vpn_ips> persist file "/etc/pf.anchors/vpn.list"

# Block all outgoing packets
block out all

# Antispoof protection
antispoof for $vpn_intf

# Allow DHCP.
pass quick on { $wifi $ether } proto udp from any port 67:68

# Allow outgoing packets to specified IPs only
pass out proto icmp from any to <allowed_vpn_ips>
pass out proto {tcp udp} from any to <allowed_vpn_ips> port $allowed_vpn_ports

# Allow traffic for VPN interfaces
pass out on $vpn_intf all
```

/etc/pf.anchors/vpn.list:

```
169.38.69.24
```

Comment: If you managed to solve the problem, can you please post the solution as an answer below?

Answer (score 0):

`pf` does not work differently on the M1 compared to the M2 or Intel CPUs.

The problem must lie in your configuration. You seem to have included something at the end of the configuration that is probably not supposed to be there:

```
#=> /etc/pf.conf:30: syntax error
```

It's a bit unclear whether this is part of your file, or some kind of copy-paste error in making your question. However, as this is a syntax error in line 30 and you've only got 4 lines - it seems a bit out of place.

In general, I would advise against editing `/etc/pf.conf` directly. It's a system file that is probably going to be overwritten when you update the system. Instead create a custom file for your own rules in the `/etc/pf.anchors` folder and load that in.

Comment: ok sorry for confusion, i updated question. i tried editing pf.conf with nano and text editor(root) - no difference.  if i use pf.anchors i get same error

Comment: Okay, now the question is quite a lot different - the files contain something different than what you originally stated. Have you noticed that you get syntax errors pointing you to specific lines in the file? - As you seem to also have syntax errors on the last line of each file - have you considered adding a newline to the files?